# Mixed data returned when client calls wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, oop, datatable, static

I have wcf service invoked by around 100 clients.
I am using Message Channel for this communication.
After i get request from client with parameters which has datatable and a string, i invoke a static method to process this data.
The processing i do is joining the datatable received from the client with the in memory cache datatable.
As given below DTReplyData is the data table.I use the same datatable for input and output i.e my data contract has only one datatable.

```
public System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message GetData(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message messageIn)
    {
        ExecutionOutput requestOperation = messageIn.GetBody<ExecutionOutput>();
        DataTable data = Cache.GetData(requestOperation.OperationName,requestOperation.DTReplyData);


    }    
public static DataTable GetData(string operationName,DataTable inputparameters)
    {
        try
        {

            return filterClientData(operationName, inputparameters);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                               

            return new DataTable();
        }
    }

    public static DataTable filterClientData(string operationName,DataTable inputparameters)
    {
        DataTable permanentcacheData = new DataTable();
        permanentcacheData = (DataTable)permanentCache[operationName];//this gets data from in memory cache

        if (permanentcacheData != null)
        {

            string[] columnNames = (from dc in inputparameters.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                                    select dc.ColumnName).ToArray();
//Helper method invoked to join tables
                DataTableHelper dt = new DataTableHelper();

            DataTable filteredData = dt.JoinTwoDataTablesOnOneColumn(inputparameters, permanentcacheData, columnNames[0], DataTableHelper.JoinType.Inner);



            filteredData.TableName = "FilteredData";

            return filteredData;
        }
        else
        {

            return permanentcacheData;
        }
    }
```

The problem i am facing is when joining happens even if i create new object the datatable helper is having some data already and data mix up happens which results in errors.Any suggesstion here is this because of static methods used?Or becuase i am using the same datamember for result and request.Ideally this shouldnt create a problem i thought.

Comment: "is this because of static methods used" - without looking closely at your code, I'd say this is a very likely root cause.  You need to be particularly careful with `static` methods, especially if they're returning data.  You can very easily run into a last-in wins scenario (i.e., two requests arrive close together and the last one is that "wins" the race, and you wind up with mixed data).

Comment: Tim ...Thanks for the answer...The root cause here was pass by refernce..Its fixed now ..

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely from using static methods.  I had a similar problem with my WCF service mixing up data, and it was fixed by removing static from my methods.